# Why is image saved gets black using imwrite?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
 grayImage=imread('coins.png');
edgeImageD = double(grayImage) - double(imdilate(grayImage,SE_3));
 OutputFileName = ['./output_images/'  'coins _edge.png'];

   imwrite((edgeImageD),OutputFileName);  
figure,imshow(edgeImageD, []),title('dilation');
```

The output image has edges but when I save it using imwrite() it gets black. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saving a `double` image, then you need to normalize all values to fall between 0 and 1 (possibly using `mat2gray`).

```
imwrite(mat2gray(edgeImageD), OutputFileName)
```

> If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes that the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values. If the data in A is single, convert A to double before writing to a GIF or TIFF file.